# Bootstrap Angular5 components, so the root isn't <app-root> necessarily

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an Angular 5 project, which I want to make component based. With a framework like Stencil, I can simply make my component and do this on any page I want:

```
<script src="~/stencil/www/build/app.js"></script>
<my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
```

and that's it. In Angular I have to do something like:

```
<base href="/angular/dist/">
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

This works pretty well, although I would love to just have a single `<script>` element, but it doesn't really matter. The problem is, this is not necessarily component based. I don't want to load `<app-root>`, because I would rather want to load `<my-custom-element>`. `<app-root>` knows nothing about which component to load, because I'm not using the build-in Angular routing.

I can make `<my-custom-element>` work in Angular perfectly, if I open `app.modules.ts` and change the `bootstrap` from this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, MyCustomComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

to this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, MyCustomComponent],
    bootstrap: [MyCustomComponent]
})
```

But then it only works for my custom component. If I have multiple elements, like `<my-second-custom-component>`, this solution does not work.

Is it possible to make any component work as the root, so I can just do the above with all the scripts and just call my custom component, and that's it?

Comment: I think that is sort of outside the scope of what angular is trying to achieve with the single page application approach. You could possibly lazy load all of your components via a secondary route though. But you will always have the single entry point element.

Comment: @Zze It might be yeah, but if I change the bootstrap to be my custom component, it works fine. I see that it's an array, but if I include both the `AppComponent` (root) and my own custom, it gives me the `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements` error. Not sure why it's an array, though.

Comment: I'm fine doing something like `<app-root component="my-custom-component"></app-root>` on all the pages I need only custom components (individually pages that has nothing to do with Angular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is possible in Angular 5 by simply adding a `componentname.module.ts` file next to the other component files. Then I simply added the code from `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { CustomComponent } from "./customcomponent.component";
import { CustomService } from "../services/CustomService";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [CustomService],
    bootstrap: [CustomComponent]
})
export class CustomModule {}
```

Then inside `main.ts` I could add this line:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CustomModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and that allowed me to simply do this inside my application:

```
<body>
    <custom-component></custom-component>
</body>
```

and that's it. Oh, and include the bundle scripts of course. I could even remove my custom component from my `app.module.ts` file, so it really knows nothing about the component.

Works flawlessly!